# Inside of a ASP.NET WebApi, how do I save an image that I created programmatically and get the URL to this image?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, botframework

I'm trying to create a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. For people who are not familiar with the Bot Framework, the bot itself it's basically a ASP.NET WebApi. Inside this application I'm creating some charts dinamically. I need however to save these charts in some format (png or jpg, most likely), and sent the url to the user. I have no previous experience with web development, so I don't know how to save the charts to a folder in the root of my app and how to generate a url pointing to it.

This is how I'm saving the chart:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("~/charts/"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("~/charts/");
}
string fileName = string.Format("~/charts/{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "png");
barChart.SaveImage(fileName, ChartImageFormat.Png);
return fileName;
```

What I need to return is the url to the file. How can I achieve this? Where should I save this file, how do I make it available and how do I get the current url in order to concatenate to the file name?

Comment: _Where should I save this file_ - I usually save it in cloud (Azure blob or AWS storage) so that its easy to share the url's to the client with/without url expiry.  In case you are planning to save it in your server itself, then I think you should designate a folder in server for these images and then expose this folder over web (probably with anonymous access).

Comment: @Developer I have no problem with the image expiring. In fact, after the session between bot and user ends I'll have to delete the image.

Comment: I would suggest Azure blob storage for this, again might be a personal preference - so do not take a decision on my words. Advantages I see with azure (or any cloud) are: *Security* - The url will not have any info about your server or you dont have to worry about your server security | url expiry could be set, *Easy Management* - the api's are pretty easy to consume

Comment: @Developer Thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into Azure Blob Storage right now, since I'll use Azure to host the application anyway.

Comment: ooh is it? If you are planning to host your app in Azure, then take my word, go for blob storage :)

Comment: @arthur You could also try to save your image as a filestream, if you are using SQL server. This might help you  : http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server/105-store-save-images-in-sql-server.html